# Kotlin data class and Bean validation: @NotNull on Double fields does not work

Tags: validation, kotlin

Here is data class:

```
data class TransactionReq(
        @field:NotNull val min: Double?,
        @field:NotNull val max: Double?
)
```

But if I do not pass min, like this:

```
{
    "max": 50
}
```

validation is passed.